# Split a UIBezierPath into 2 parts

Tags: ios, swift, uibezierpath, graphicspath

Is possible to split a path in 2 distinct paths?! I'm trying to implement a rubber that erase partially a path, and was wandering if there's an elegant way to do this.

Otherwise i'll simply use the same color of the background...

Comment: It is not too difficult to do this. Please see my post for this SO question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25722680/can-i-make-a-half-bezier-from-full-bezier/25729459#25729459).

Comment: How can i apply that method to arbitrary paths?